# Why is spring.jmx.enabled=false needed to prevent duplicate DataSource MBeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jndi

I am building a Spring Boot web application deployed to Tomcat which builds a DataSource bean using JNDI.

I have the following entry in `application.properties` to prevent a duplicate DataSource MBean from being created in JMX

```
# Prevent Spring from automatically exposing beans to JMX. Tomcat automatically creates an MBean when setting the
# JNDI data source, and an error gets thrown if spring then tries to add the data source MBean itself.
spring.jmx.enabled=false
```

But my question is this: there is a property called `spring.datasource.jmx-enabled` that is set to `false` by default. This seems like a fine grained setting that should disable only DataSource MBeans from being exposed by Spring, right? But that is not the case. Unless I disable all JMX, the DataSource MBean will be duplicated.